# Restart Play Framework Activator using a script on mac & linux

Tags: scala, unix, playframework, typesafe-activator

I am trying to develop a script that can restart an activator instance running on a specified port. I normally run my activator project at port 15000 and I am aiming to have it restarted using the script. I can then later call that script from a web page to have activator restarted remotely etc.

So far I found a really handy utility in Linux called `fuser` which can find a process listening at a specified port and kill it. Something like:

`fuser -k 15000/tcp` which works fine on linux but NOT on a mac.

I guess I would also need to somehow track the activator project location to start it later.

Please let me know your suggestions and comments on how this can be done.

Comment: The easiest would be removing the file `RUNNING_PID`. And then just call `activator start` or whatever you want. You can even change the location of the pid file with: `-Dpidfile.path=instance1`. BTW: The pid file contains the process id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a bash file for this. It works on Linux and Mac OS.

It's named loader.sh and put into your distributions root.

To stop it uses the `kill` command and the PID stored in `RUNNING_PID`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change IP address and port here
address="127.0.0.1"
port="9000"

# Get directory and add it to PATH
dir="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
export PATH="$dir:$dir/bin:$PATH"

function start() {
    # Check if we started already
    [ -f $dir/RUNNING_PID ] && return

    echo -n "Starting"

    # You can specify a config file with -Dconfig.resource
    # or a secret with -Dplay.crypto.secret
    myApp -Dhttp.port=$port -Dhttp.address=$address > /dev/null &

    echo "...started"
}

function stop() {
    [ -f $dir/RUNNING_PID ] || return
    echo -n "Stopping"
    kill -SIGTERM $(cat $dir/RUNNING_PID)
    while [ -f $dir/RUNNING_PID ]
    do
        sleep 0.5
    done

    echo "...stopped"
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: loader.sh start|stop|restart"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```