# Restart play app with script

Tags: java, playframework

i have created a simple app and used `./activator dist` script to make an executable. It has created a zip archive and in `bin` folder created a script `play-java` which allows me to run my app.

Now - what I need is to run it this way:

```
if running -> restart
else start
```

Is there a way to use this generated script this way? Or use something different to get this result?

Comment: Look on http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/topics/play.html  SBT native packager can create instalation package and system service that is easier to manage

Comment: There is a similar question. Maybe it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447448/restart-play-framework-activator-using-a-script-on-mac-linux/35453078#35453078